# How do you say it when you are extremely relying on someone or something?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

I want to say "*I'm at the whim of X*"  but it just doesn't sound right.  There is another word for this but for some reason I just can't think of it.

Comment: Not sure if you are looking for something  like: "*I'm at the mercy of X*" or "*I'm at X's beck and call*"  which I get from your *whim* example, but your title leans more toward 'I am completely dependent on X"

Comment: That's the one!!!  "mercy of"  I had a brain fart.  You should have made that an answer so that I can accept it :)

Comment: "Utterly dependent on" works, too.

Comment: And a metaphorical phrase that may be apt is "I'm under X's thumb."

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are thinking of: *at the mercy of...* which is fairly similar to the expression you quote.
Other words could be *dependent on*, *reliant on* or *heavily supported by* in a more passive sense.

Answer (score 0):

You may also say:

> "I'm ***overdependent*** on X"

ODO:

> **[overdependent](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/overdependent)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> See [overdependence](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/overdependence)
>
> ‘The signs are usually a fall in academic performance, problems
>   socialising with friends at school, or clingy, overdependent
>   behaviour.’
>
> **[overdependence](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/overdependence)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> Dependence to an excessive degree:
>   ‘overdependence on the tourism
>   sector’

Answer (score -1):

Dependent upon, counting on, defenceless, helpless, reliant, vulnerable, weak, conditional, contingent, determined by, liable to, relative, subject to, subordinate

Comment: This is just a list from a thesaurus. The OP is expected to have bothered to look at a thesaurus beforehand so this is not relevant. If you think one or more of them are particularly good, please edit and explain why they fit.

Answer (score -3):

The word you're looking for is precarious.

See http://www.dictionary.com/browse/precarious